# redirecting sql output to a file in a shell script

Tags: sql, shell

I am facing an issue while executing the following script snippet.

```
$ORACLEHOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DBUSER/$DBPASSWORD <<EOF
    set pages 0 feedback off
    SELECT * FROM ERR_STG_ROAMING_PARTNER;

EOF > Err_File.txt
```

The following error message appears.

```
./Roaming.sh: line 213: warning: here-document at line 206 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
./Roaming.sh: line 214: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ORACLEHOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DBUSER/$DBPASSWORD > Err_File.txt <<EOF
    set pages 0 feedback off
    SELECT * FROM ERR_STG_ROAMING_PARTNER;

EOF
```

That is, specify the output redirection before the input heredoc redirection. The shell expects `EOF` to be on its own on the line terminating the heredoc.

The error message you are getting is the shell complaining about finding end-of-file (of the script file) before finding `EOF`. The usage of `EOF` for the heredoc delimiter might lead to some confusion here!

Comment: Thanks mate! great help!